# Xcode: Impossible to use c++ with Scenekit?

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, scenekit

I'm a beginner with Xcode...
I'm trying to use openCV c++ with Scenekit=> to make an AR scene.
Well, I was too optimistic.

1/I started to use the default XCode template for game.=> works!

2/openCV without scenekit=> works

3/ mixing...

I imported some c++ headers in the gameviewController file (basically a UIViewController with scenekit inside).

If I let it so, I get compiler error (cstddef not defined). Fair enough, it's C++ so, from what I read, I just have to rename .m to .mm
But, in this case, I get a full list of linker errors such as Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNAction", referenced from:

=> I guess it is more tricky to mix objective C and C++ but on a simpler project, without Scenekit but with a very similar code otherwise, it worked nicely.

Any clue or guide for mixing them? Should I use swift?

Thanks a lot,

Michael

Comment: Integrating Objective-C and C++ is not trivial so it's not really something that can be answered here.  Do you at least understand the issues?

Comment: I'm on latest XCode (updated yesterday)

Comment: I'll take that as a "no" then.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly add "SceneKit.framework" to the link phase of your build settings? (I'm wondering if ObjC++ is compatible with modules)

Answer (score 5):

I just need to add "SceneKit.framework" to `Link Binary With Libraries`:
[image: Link Binary wit]

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I spend hours trying to work this out, turns out the tutorial missed this out!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.  I had a pure Objective-C class, simply named "GameViewController.m".  To turn it into an Obj-C++ class, change the ".m" to ".mm".

However, just by changing the extension, the linker spat back 13 undefined symbols....

```
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNTransaction", referenced from: ...
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNFloor", referenced from: ...
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNMaterial", referenced from: ...
etc...
```

To get around this, just create a different (new) Obj-C++ class, with a .mm extension, and place your C++ code in that class.
Now you can instantiate that new class from the class containing SceneKit calls and call the methods in the new Obj-C++ class.

Inside the GameViewcontroller.m class:

```
... 
 scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/grid.dae"];
 kinematics = [[KinematicScene alloc] init];
 [kinematics setupCharacters];
 ...
```

And inside the new Obj-C++ class (KinematicsScene.mm)

```
@implementation KinematicScene
{
    AI::Location *location;
}

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
       AI::KinematicSeek* seek = new AI::KinematicSeek[2];

       location = new AI::Location[2];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setupCharacters
{
  .....
}

... etc ....

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Disable module support [CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES, -fmodules]. This has user experience downsides. Read the online help for this setting before disabling it, and also be aware that if you disable it you will become responsible for hunting down the libraries and frameworks you need to link against, and this can be tedious if you are not an old hand.
2. Build and (attempt to) link. Add the frameworks and libraries you need to resolve the link errors. I recommend creating a group in your project and directing it to your SDK, then adding the frameworks and libraries relative to that SDK.